# Callstack aware Variable Liveness Analysis

Tags: algorithm, compiler-construction, static-analysis

### Problem

I have a system (basically an interpreter) with a global table of identifiers pointing to resources. I am trying to perform liveness analysis for these resources on the basic blocks
of instructions that the system executes.

So far I have been doing this successfully using the traditional `Gen` + `Kill` sets [approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live-variable_analysis).

My problem now is that there is a 'function call' instruction with the usual call stack semantics (execution resumes with the next instruction after a return instruction is hit, arbitrarily nesting). Because of the global resource table, functions cannot be analyzed separately.

---

### Attempted Solutions

My first thought was to just split the basic block at the call, add the callee as the only successor and then add the 'after return' BB as a successor of the callee's tails.
But this is obviously not optimal as other callers of the same callee could never end up in that block.

My second thought was to add a separate BB that basically concatenates the callee with the remaining instructions of the caller, but I think recursion makes that approach infeasable.

---

### Question

Can you describe an algorithm (or link a paper) that solves this problem? I was not able to find anything online so far, but that might be due to my lack of experience in the domain.
If it turns out that this is not solvable (Halting Problem ?), any resources or descriptions of heuristic approaches usable in practice would be great.